# How to fix illegal characters in URL in Java?

Tags: java, url, encoding, uri

I would like a function that detects invalid characters in a URL and replaces them with their encoded equivalent. E.G.:

```
ensureValidUrl("http://example.com/invalid url/") // "http://example.com/invalid%20url/"
```

I had tried `URLEncoder.encode`, but this also encodes the protocol, which I don't want.

Comment: The multiple-argument constructors of the [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) class will escape characters as needed, but if you are starting with a (possibly bad) pre-composed URL, those constructors may not be of much help.  Note that `new URI(string)` does not escape characters.

Comment: Indeed I am starting with a complete URL as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static String getValidURL(String invalidURLString){
    try {
        // Convert the String and decode the URL into the URL class
        URL url = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(invalidURLString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));

        // Use the methods of the URL class to achieve a generic solution
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        // return String or
        // uri.toURL() to return URL object
        return uri.toString();
    } catch (URISyntaxException | UnsupportedEncodingException | MalformedURLException ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using a combination of URI and URL classes, your solution can be achieved. More on [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) and [Charsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).

Usage:

```
System.out.println(getValidURL("http://example.com/invalid url/"));
// http://example.com/invalid%20url/
```

Comment: This looks great! I will test it tomorrow, many thanks!